# Are ring homomorphisms always unital if the rings have $1_{R}$

Tags: ring-theory, ring-homomorphism

I know according to some textbooks, rings do not have to contain $1$. But if I define rings to have $1$, are all ring homomorphisms unital? Here's my attempt to prove this:

Let $\phi:R\rightarrow S$ be a ring homomorphism. $\forall x\in R$, $\phi(x)=\phi(1\cdot x)=\phi(1)\phi(x)\implies \phi(1)=1$.

Is there anything wrong with my proof? If my proof is correct, then what's the point of classifying unital and non-unital ring homomorphisms? There are a lot of good reasons why rings should include $1$. It is better to for rings to have $1$, so according to this definition, all ring homomorphisms are unital.

Comment: Consider $0 \to R$ for any unital nonzero $R$.

Comment: @MarkSaving Like I said, I defined rings to have 1. So I will not consider 0 here.

Comment: Consider $(1,0) \in R_1 \times R_2$.  It looks like an identity in $R_1 \times \{0\}$ but it's not the identity $(1,1) \in R_1 \times R_2$.  (all $\phi(1)\phi(x) = \phi(x)$ tells you is that $\phi(1)$ looks like an identity on $\phi(R) \subset S$)

Comment: @Irene $0$ does contain 1. $0 = 1$ in $0$.

Comment: The condition $\forall x \in R,\, \phi(1)\phi(x) = \phi(x) = \phi(x)\phi(1)$ only means that $\phi(1)$ is the “$1$” of $\phi(R)$, not of $S$.

Comment: The zero ring has a $1$, it just happens to be the same number as $0$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

u could only deduce that $\phi(x) (1-\phi(1))=0$ for every $x\in R$(there is no cancellation for multplication in general) , if $S$ is an integral domain and $\phi$ isn't the zero map, , then u can conclude $\phi(1)=1$,so u need  extra assumption on the ring , or u define ring homomorphisms to satisfy $\phi(1) =1$.

Comment: Indeed, a nice example is $$\phi:R \rightarrow R\times R, x\mapsto (x, 0).$$ It is not unital and not the zero homomorphism.

Comment: obsiously!just a typo (edited)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a concrete example of what can go wrong.

Consider the ring $\mathbf Z/(6)$.  Its subset $\{0, 3 \bmod 6\}$ is a "subset with ring structure" since $3+3 = 0$ and $(3)(3) = 3$, so $3$ is the multiplicative identity of that two-element ring.  So $f \colon \mathbf Z/(2) \to \mathbf Z/(6)$ by $f(x \bmod 2) = 3x \bmod 6$ is an additive and multiplicative mapping (because $3^2 = 3$ in $\mathbf Z/(6)$).  It does *not* send the multiplicative identity of $\mathbf Z/(2)$ to the multiplicative identity of $\mathbf Z/(6)$.